# I am trying to open one modal from another modal in React.js. but previous modal kept open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, jsx

**It is a login page component in that I want to open forgot password component. Both components are modal. But when I clicked on Forgot password the login page modal is kept open. I just closed the login pop-up, when I click on it, forgot the password component**

[image]

Below is the login pop-up component

```
    //Initial state for Modal
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
   //Close Modal
    const handleClose = () => {
        setShow(false)
    };
    //On this click Modal get visiblr
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    
    
 <>

    <p onClick={handleShow}>LOGIN</p>
    //Login Modal
    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} className="p-5 authpop">

        <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Title>
                Log In
            </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        //Form submit
        <Form className=" p-3" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3 validateInput">
                <Form.Label>Enter email id</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control ref={emailRef} className="inputField" id="loginEmail" type="email" placeholder="Your email"
                    onChange={validateEmail}
                />
                <span className="errorMsg" >{emailError}</span>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3 validateInput">
                <Form.Label>Enter Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control ref={passwRef} className="inputField" id="loginPass" type="password" placeholder="Password"
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <Button className="SelectLogBtns LoginBtns" variant="primary" type="Submit">
                    Log In
                </Button>
            </Form.Group>
            <div className="errorMsg d-flex mb-3" >{error}</div>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3 loginlsRw">
                <div className="forgottLink eqSpace justify-content-start">     
                    //ForgottPassword Component link  
                    <ForgottPassw/>
                </div>                   
           
        </Form>
    </Modal>
    </>
```

```
 //Here is forgot password component 
`const ForgottPassw = () => {
    const [Fogshow, setFogShow] = useState(false);    
    const [showBtn, setShowBtn] = useState(false);
    const handleFogClose = () => setFogShow(false);
    const handleFogShow = () => setFogShow(true);
    const { forgottPass } = useUserAuth();       
    return (
        <>            <p onClick={handleFogShow}>Forgott Password</p>
            <Modal show={Fogshow} onHide={handleFogClose} className="p-5 authpop">
                <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={handleFogClose}>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Form className="p-3" onSubmit={handleForgott}>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3 validateInput">
                        <Form.Label>Enter email id</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control ref={emailRef} className="inputField" id="loginEmail" type="email" placeholder="Your email"
                            onChange={validateFogEmail}
                        />
                        <span className="errorMsg" >{emailError}</span>
                    </Form.Group>
```

//Reset Link
<Form.Group style={{ visibility: showBtn ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }} className="mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">

Send Reset Link

</Form.Group>


</>
);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the login modal isn't gonna go anywhere unless you make it that way. At the moment the login modal is rendered when the `show` state is `true`. Even if you click the forget-password link, it will stay open because you aren't reverting the state to `false`. Wherever is the logic to make the forget modal visible, include `setShow(false)` for login modal. Because I can't say what you are doing in your `ForgetPassword` file and your main component, I can't say much.

I know this is a simple workaround you can do other things to make it work, but simply you can just pass both `show` and `setShow` as props to the to the forget-password component like this.

```js
<ForgottPassw show={show} setShow={setShow} />
```

and then in your functional component, you can take the props and change the `handleFogShow` function to this

```js
const ForgottPassw = ({show, setShow}) => {
    //...
    const handleFogShow = () => {
        setShow(false);
        setFogShow(true);
    }
}
```

let me know if it fix the issue.

Comment: thank you :)  I have added Forgot password component in the above. Login and forgotpassword components are separate but I am not able to setShow(false) in forgotpassword . I tried with useReducer but it won't work

Comment: @YogeshPednekar I edited the answer, check it and let me know if it solves the issue

Comment: Thank you for solution @nabroleonx - It works but forgottpassword modal gets closed immediaetly.

Comment: My bad, `setShow(false);` should come before `setFogShow(true);`, i corrected the `handleFogShow` function, check it out. The forget password was closing immediately because the component rerenders after `setShow(false)`  runs and it sets the fogShow to false. Let me know if it fixes the issue

Comment: @nabroleonx- I tried this solution as well but it gets close immediately. What should I do ?

Comment: @YogeshPednekar It is kind of hard to notice the problem without seeing how all the pieces fit. can you make a codesandbox and send me the link, since I will be able to interact  with the code, I can suggest something then

Comment: @nabroleonx- Here is the code sandbox link           
          https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-microservice-fylzb?file=/src/components/Loginpage.jsx   I have removed other code only kept necessary. On click on login modal. the login page shows up. And, on click on forgot password it is not show

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is. I don't know how I didn't see it the first time. You are rendering the forget password modal inside the login modal so, that's why it closes immediately. One thing you can do is have one modal for both login n forget password and conditionally render the content of the modal or you can render the modal outside of the login modal. its up to you.

Comment: Thank you, @nabroleonx- I will try as you suggested and show you :). You helped me a lot.

Comment: Its alright, Here I wrote a simple code snippet for your [`Loginpage.jsx`](https://pastebin.com/MfmCg6m3). check out the link and copy and paste the code in the file and try it then let me know if it is giving you the desired output.